# Add values in new columns based on condition from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe (I have some problems properly showing the table, please refer to the last part for the dictionary):

```
 account_id contract_id date_activated  term_months 2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-03-01 00:00:00 2021-04-01 00:00:00 2021-05-01 00:00:00 2021-06-01 00:00:00 2021-07-01 00:00:00 2021-08-01 00:00:00 2021-09-01 00:00:00 2021-10-01 00:00:00 2021-11-01 00:00:00 2021-12-01 00:00:00
0   1   A   2021-01-01  1   200.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   1   B   2021-02-13  12  0.0 300.0   300.0   300.0   300.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   1   C   2021-04-06  12  0.0 0.0 0.0 400.0   400.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   1   I   2020-10-23  6   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 150.0   150.0   0.0
4   1   N   2021-11-11  6   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 100.0   100.0
5   2   K   2021-01-01  12  100.0   100.0   100.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
6   2   F   2021-03-23  6   0.0 0.0 50.0    50.0    50.0    50.0    50.0    50.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I want the result as shown (with new columns contract_type and renewal_type):

```
 account_id contract_id date_activated  term_months contract_type   renewal_type    2021-01-01 00:00:00 2021-02-01 00:00:00 2021-03-01 00:00:00 2021-04-01 00:00:00 2021-05-01 00:00:00 2021-06-01 00:00:00 2021-07-01 00:00:00 2021-08-01 00:00:00 2021-09-01 00:00:00 2021-10-01 00:00:00 2021-11-01 00:00:00 2021-12-01 00:00:00
0   1   A   2021-01-01  1   Original    Regular 200.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   1   B   2021-02-13  12  Upgrade Regular 0.0 300.0   300.0   300.0   300.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   1   C   2021-04-06  12  Upgrade Early   0.0 0.0 0.0 400.0   400.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   1   I   2020-10-23  6   Winback Regular 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 150.0   150.0   0.0
4   1   N   2021-11-11  6   Renewal Early   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 100.0   100.0
5   2   K   2021-01-01  12  Original    Regular 100.0   100.0   100.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
6   2   F   2021-03-23  6   Renewal Early   0.0 0.0 50.0    50.0    50.0    50.0    50.0    50.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

You can download the excel file on this linke for a sample copy of the result: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16BLoSugMaDdB8Qac2ATJRBLRvx3HCIus/view?usp=sharing

Each account has several contracts. I want to add two columns based on the transactions per month (from the fifth column and so on).

The renewal type should either be "Regular" or "Early". It's "Regular" when it's the "Original" or a "Winback" contract. It's also "Regular" if the previous contract has ended its term last month and the payment for the new contract is on the next month. It's "Early" when a new contract was made for the same account yet the previous contract has not yet expired or ended its term (based on the term_months).

The contract type should either be "Original", "Renewal", "Upgrade", or "Winback". It's "Original" if it's the first contract for that account. It's "Winback" if a new contract was made after 4 months of no payments/transactions from the previous contract. It's an "Upgrade" if it is not a "Winback" and the new contract has payments greater than the previous contract. If it does not fall under "Original", "Upgrade", or "Winback", it's considered as "Renewal".

Tried doing it with this code but there are some problems because it classifies some "Original" as "Winback" (for the contract_type) and some "Early" as "Regular" (for the renewal_type):

```
def get_types(monthly_payments):
    def f(s):
        check = monthly_payments.loc[
            (s.date_activated.year == monthly_payments.index.year) &
            (s.date_activated.month == monthly_payments.index.month)
            ].iloc[0]

        if check.wb == 0:
            # If rolling sum of 4 months prior is 0
            s['contract_type'] = 'Winback'
        elif check.og_upg == 0:
            # If Prior Month is 0
            s['contract_type'] = 'Original'

        elif check.max_pmt > check.og_upg:
            # If Prior Month is not missing and current month is more
            s['contract_type'] = 'Upgrade'
        else:
            s['contract_type'] = 'Renewal'

        if check.early:
            # If Early
            s['renewal_type'] = 'Early'
        else:
            s['renewal_type'] = 'Regular'
        return s

    return f

def apply_types(g):
    # Get Non Payment Info
    account_info = g[g.columns[:4]]
    # Transpose Monthly Payments To Rows
    monthly_payments = g.loc[:, g.columns[4:]].T
    # Make Sure Index is DT
    monthly_payments.index = pd.to_datetime(monthly_payments.index)
    # Get Check for is early based on number of payments
    monthly_payments['early'] = monthly_payments.astype(bool).sum(axis=1) > 1
    # Max Payment In Month
    monthly_payments['max_pmt'] = monthly_payments.max(axis=1)
    # 1 Month Prior
    monthly_payments['og_upg'] = monthly_payments.max_pmt.shift().fillna(0)
    # Rolling Sum of 4 Months Prior
    monthly_payments['wb'] = monthly_payments.max_pmt \
        .rolling(min_periods=0, window=4).sum().shift()
    # Concat New Columns With Original Payment Information
    return pd.concat((
        account_info.apply(get_types(monthly_payments), axis=1),
        g[g.columns[4:]]
    ), axis=1)

df = df.groupby('account_id', as_index=False).apply(apply_types).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Here's the dictionary for the dataframe:

```
{'account_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2},
 'contract_id': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'I', 4: 'N', 5: 'K', 6: 'F'},
 'date_activated': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-02-13 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-04-06 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-10-23 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-11-11 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-03-23 00:00:00')},
 'term_months': {0: 1, 1: 12, 2: 12, 3: 6, 4: 6, 5: 12, 6: 6},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0): {0: 200.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 100.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 100.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 100.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 150.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 150.0,
  4: 100.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 100.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0}}
```

Here's the dictionary for the results:

```
{'account_id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2},
 'contract_id': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'I', 4: 'N', 5: 'K', 6: 'F'},
 'date_activated': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-02-13 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-04-06 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-10-23 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-11-11 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-03-23 00:00:00')},
 'term_months': {0: 1, 1: 12, 2: 12, 3: 6, 4: 6, 5: 12, 6: 6},
 'contract_type': {0: 'Original',
  1: 'Upgrade',
  2: 'Upgrade',
  3: 'Winback',
  4: 'Renewal',
  5: 'Original',
  6: 'Renewal'},
 'renewal_type': {0: 'Regular',
  1: 'Regular',
  2: 'Early',
  3: 'Regular',
  4: 'Early',
  5: 'Regular',
  6: 'Early'},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0): {0: 200.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 100.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 100.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 100.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 300.0,
  2: 400.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 50.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 150.0,
  4: 0.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 150.0,
  4: 100.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0},
 datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 0, 0): {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 100.0,
  5: 0.0,
  6: 0.0}}
```

Comment: That's not a simple one...you should offer a bounty for that if you want it to be solved

Comment: I included the code I tried it with. Maybe, you can refer to it.